# VisualStudio 2019 doesn't show the same NET frameworks as VisualStudio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have installed VS2019 community (on my **F:\** because **C:\** is getting low on diskspace).

Now I start a new C# Class library. When I try to set the target framework I can only pick **.NET** Standard **1.0** upto **2.1**
When I do the exact same steps in my VS2017 I can also pick for example **.NET Framework 4.6.1** and several others ranging from **4.8** upto **4.8**

Maybe this is related... when I try to add a COM object to the references in 2017 it shows as an option in the dialog but in 2019 it doesn't. Maybe because I'm stuck in **.NET framework 2.0**?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely the same behavior for VS2017 also. What I suppose you have done is that in VS 2017 you have chosen a .Net Framework template for the Class Library project. When you tried to create a class library in VS2019, you mush have selected the .Net Standard template for the class library.

You should not be able to switch between .Net Standard and .Net Framework after you create the project so I suppose you just got confused between the templates.

Comment: @Alban I completely understand as it got me once too :)